# Buzzing ringing in boost converter regulator when using PWM in lower duty cycle

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, boost, switching-regulator, buck-boost

I designed a boost converter using TI LMR62014XMF, to convert 5 V to 12 V for using as backlight source in my LVDS display adapter.

The LCD display panel needs 12 V at 0.5 A max for backlight driving.

The PWM is directly fed to the LCD display.

So at fully duty cycle 100% there is no buzzing ringing in the LMR60214, but when I reduce the PWM to reduce the brightness, say below 95% duty cycle the ringing/ buzzing starts. I traced the noise back to the switching regulator LMR60214 itself.

I tried using different input/ output capacitors, but no use.

All the capacitors are rated for min 25 V. 0805 ceramic capacitors.

I changed the inductor with 4 other inductors but still no use.
Inductors were rated for 10 uH, minimum 2.5 A.

I'm new to this and I used the same example layout as provided in the datasheet.

What puzzles me is, at full power consumption/ max brightness, there is no ringing.
But only when at lower duty cycles the ringing is present.

Even tried out with different PWM frequencies, from 20 Hz to 20 kHz but still no use.

One more thing I tried is using a 12 V adapter to inject the 12 V voltage for the LCD backlight.

No buzzing sound from the 12 V mains adapter at any PWM duty cycle or frequency used for backlight control.

Another problem I found is when the enable signal is not high, the output voltage is 5 V which is the same as the input. What could be the cause of this? Is it normal? I guess it could be because of the inductor, but I don't know why.

I have attached the schematic and the layout.

Any pointers will be greatly helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does it look on your scope? For low duty cycle, it's popular to have skip cycle or burst mode to save power. May be audible.

Comment: Note that there is a direct path from Vin through the inductor and the output diode, so when the part is not enabled, the output voltage will equal the input voltage minus a diode drop.  This is normal for boost converters, or at least those without an output disconnect feature.